# Tool to convert markdown within html table tags

Tags: html, converters, markdown

I am editing a website which has been migrated from markdown to a cms. The developers migrated the content but the tool to handle the conversion has failed to convert any markdown that was within table cells, ending up with markup in an html field in the cms like:

```
    <tr>
        <td>webResources</td>
        <td>edm:WebResources</td>
        <td>[WebResource](#WebResource)</td>
        <td>A collection of webResource objects</td>
    </tr>
```

On some pages there may be 40 links or more so I am looking for a tool, ideally online, to re-process them on a page by page basis (but not cell by cell!) and finish off the job.  Nothing I have found converts any links within html table tags like these. Anyone know of anything?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of numerous other questions (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30647475/866026) one). Have you tried setting `markdown=1` on the wrapping HTML element? Some Markdown parsers support that, but without more info, I can't say if yours does. Some parsers also support turning on parsing Markdown inside HTML globally. However, that is not the default behavior. You'll need to read the docs to see how to turn it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-html) does this with the `markdown_in_html_blocks` option which is enabled by default.