# How to insert markdown within HTML tags, such that both are rendered properly?

Tags: html, markdown

I have noticed that on my website using markdown within HTML tags causes the markdown to be left unrendered (that is, treated as just plain text). Such as in this example:

```
<div class="note">
**NOTE:**
* I merely study computing and related topics in my spare time, I have no formal training in technology or the associated legalities, so while I am trying to ensure this post (especially the glossary section) is as accurate as I can, I cannot guarantee its accuracy. If you have any corrections or edit recommendations please forward them to my email address.
* Hyperlinks to third-party resources (including Wikipedia) that I cannot guarantee the accuracy are included in this article.
</div>
```

where this is the relevant `div.note` SCSS class:

```
div.note {
    padding: 1px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 160, 160);
    background-color: #ffa0a0;
}
```

is rendered as:

[image]

Is there a way of solving this problem, so that both markdown and HTML syntax is rendered properly in the final webpage result? I do not think this is relevant, but in case it is, the website of mine on which this problem exists is Jekyll-powered.

I am using the redcarpet extension for markdown rendering.

Comment: It will depend entirely on the markdown parser you're using.

Comment: I'll add that info to my question.

Comment: @zzzzBov I've added the parser (redcarpet), granted that was almost half an hour ago, any ideas of an answer?

Comment: pandoc does this: http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-html

Comment: Although not an exact duplicate (it refers to Jekyll/Kramdown rather than Jekyll/Redcarpet), this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647475/grouping-markdown-elements-in-to-div-element-or-custom-html-tag/30668958#30668958

Comment: I just checked and Redcarpet doesn't appear to support this (I did not check third party extensions), however, the other Markdown parser for Jekyll, Kramdown, does support Markdown syntax inside HTML. See the [docs](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks) for more (and the link in my previous comment for an explanation).